# my private github dependency will not install its own dependencies (node modules)

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a private package -- let's call it `magic` -- that I install into a project of mine, `blog`. It successfully gets installed into `blog`, under `node_modules`. However, the package itself, `magic`, has its own application dependencies and yet when I install magic into `blog` using yarn as a dependency, magic does not install its dependencies. It's missing its own `node_modules` folder.

```
blog
 - lib/
 - package.json (states magic as a dependency and successfully installs it with yarn)
 - node_modules/
   - magic (successfully installs magic)
     - lib/
     - (no node_modules?)
     - package.json
```

How can I build a package such that when another app installs it, the package will also create its own `node_modules`?

Comment: Do you have a package.json in the root of your github project?

Comment: @Peter Ried, yes, I do.

Comment: And the `package.json` of `magic` contains your dependency list?

Comment: Yes, it does. under `dependencies`

Comment: does installing via `npm` as opposed to `yarn` provide a different output?

Comment: @PeterReid I tried that too. There is no difference. Good idea, however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147497/discussion-between-peter-reid-and-robertjewell).

Comment: Did you find out an explanation ????